# IE truncates words containing "&" when building dynamic list from json object with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

While testing the compatibility of my function in different browsers, I found a behaviour I didn't know about in IE.

It looks like words get truncated when they contain the character "&".

The javascript function gets a json object from the server (c#) and dynamically build a list. What happens is if the object's description is "Test & Test", then while Chrome and Firefox display the description as expected, IE displays "Test ".

The only solution I've found is to press F12 and force the "Document Mode" to "IE9 standards".
I've tried different doctypes, used  with different content values, I've included the javascript ie9.js file (the one that makes MSIE behave like a  standards-compliant browser), wrapped the object's description in div,span,p or any kind of tag available in html, without result so far.

Here is the javascript function that builds the list:

```
$.each(data, function (ind, c) {
  if ($container.find('option:contains("' + c.Description + '")').length > 0) {
    var name = c.Description;
    var $div = $('<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;width:80%;float:left;" />').html(name).attr({ 'id': c._id });
    var $o = $('<li />').html($div).css({ 'margin': 0, 'padding': 0, 'width': '100%', 'font-size': '1em' })
    .addClass((ind % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'));
    if (!(c.IsDefault)) {
      var $actionContainer = $('<div />').css({ 'height': 17, 'width': 17, 'float': 'right' });
      var $action = $('<button />').html('Delete')
      .css({ 'height': 16, 'width': 16 })
      .button({
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-trash' },
        text: false
      }).click(function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this object from the list?")) {
          var objectId= $(this).parent().parent().children(':first-child').attr('id');
          var server = $('#GroupServer').val();
          delete($container, server, objectId, $dialog);
        }
      });
      $action.removeClass('ui-corner-all');
      $actionContainer.append($action);
      $o.append($actionContainer);
    }
    $ul.append($o);
  }
});
```

And the json object:

```
{ "_id":1,"Description":"Test & Test", "IsDefault":true }
```

Has anyone seen that behaviour before? and is it possible to force IE's Document mode to IE9 standards in other ways than the one I've already tried?
Kind regards,

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

What are you changing the document mode **from**? Is it rendering in quirks mode originally? If so that is most likely causing your issues, make sure you have a valid doctype, valid HTML etc.

Comment: I'm changing it from IE8 standards. Does not work in Quirks mode, and I'm using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml">

Comment: Is it encoded in the document? ie. when it does `.find('option:contains("' + c.Description + '")')` will it find 'Test & Test' or 'Test &amp; Test' ?

Comment: I've replaced "&" with &amp; on the server side, and then replaced &amp; with "&" for the find function, using "test & Test" for the find part, and "Test &amp; Test" for the display part.